# Data in column not changed

Tags: sql-server-2005, history

I have sql 2005 and when i run below query, data from RealTimeLog table transfer to History
but when new data come in RealTimeLog table old data not changed by new one
means OutTime data is not changed with new data from RealTimeLog.

```
INSERT INTO History
            (UserID,
             UserName,
             LogDate,
             [InTime],
             [OutTime])
SELECT UserID,
       UserName,
       [LogDate],
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR, MIN(CONVERT(DATETIME, [LogTime], 108)), 108),
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR, MAX(CONVERT(DATETIME, [LogTime], 108)), 108)
FROM   RealTimeLog
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   History H
                   WHERE  H.UserID = RealTimeLog.UserID
                          AND H.UserName = RealTimeLog.UserName
                          AND H.LogDate = RealTimeLog.LogDate)
GROUP  BY UserID,
          UserName,
          [LogDate]
ORDER  BY UserID,
          [LogDate]
```

for ex.

```
1   Shanks  02/05/2010  9:00   10:00
```

if new Max time generated suppose 11:00 in RealtimeLog then it is not inserted in History table and output remain same as above.

Answer (score 1):

As it´s explicitly in your condition, you just insert new records when it brigs a new userid or new user name or new LogDate. In the case that you show this condition is not met.

You have to add an update clause after that for the cases where the Log already exists `... where Exists...` or `inner join` as follows:

```
UPDATE H
SET [OutTime] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR,MAX(CONVERT(DATETIME,R.[LogTime],108)),108)
FROM History H inner join
     RealTimeLog R ON H.UserID = R.UserID
                  AND H.UserName = R.UserName
                  AND H.LogDate = R.LogDate
GROUP BY H.UserID,
         H.UserName,
         H.LogDate
HAVING [OutTime]<>CONVERT(NVARCHAR,MAX(CONVERT(DATETIME,R.[LogTime],108)),108)
```

In SQL Server 2008, a nice approach is the MERGE syntax: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: `MERGE` doesn't exist in SS 2005

Comment: Thanks. I made the clarification in the answer.